# OpenGL QT 4 code does not display QLogo (helloworld example) in QT5

Tags: qt, opengl, mingw, version

The application compiles and runs with no compiler errors however no Q logo is displayed.
I have taken the QT Logo OpenGL example http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/opengl-hellogl/
and attempted to compile in QT version 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32bit) . I am aware that there is a change in the way OpenGL is used in version 5 from the older version 4. I have modified some of the code from a working GL example and it still does not work. My bet is the problem exists in the QtLogo because I have changed nothing in those files. So I am completely puzzled being a newbie to OpenGL.
I hope to have provided a descent problem statement. Answering this will help so many others unlock the mysteries of QT OpenGL changes. It is so frustrating.

1) QT version 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32bit) - Installed with Qt 5.2.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 634 MB) installer
2) Windows 7, tried 32bit and 64bit
3) Intel CPUs (used two different Intel based computers)
4) The application does work correctly in QT version 4

5) The code is available for download http://1drv.ms/1g88ScS

Here is the code:

hellogl.pro

```
# HELLOGL


#VPATH += ../shared
#INCLUDEPATH += ../shared

QT += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = hellogl
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES       += main.cpp \
                 window.cpp \
                 glwidget.cpp \
                 qtlogo.cpp

HEADERS       += window.h \
                glwidget.h \
                qtlogo.h

FORMS         += window.ui
```

GLWIDGET.H

```
// glwidget.h


#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QGLWidget>

class QtLogo;

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWidget();

    QSize minimumSizeHint() const;
    QSize sizeHint() const;

public slots:
    void setXRotation(int angle);
    void setYRotation(int angle);
    void setZRotation(int angle);

signals:
    void xRotationChanged(int angle);
    void yRotationChanged(int angle);
    void zRotationChanged(int angle);

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

private:
    QtLogo *logo;
    int xRot;
    int yRot;
    int zRot;
    QPoint lastPos;
    QColor qtGreen;
    QColor qtPurple;
};

#endif
```

qtlogo.h

```
//qtlogo.h


#ifndef QTLOGO_H
#define QTLOGO_H

//#include <QObject>
//#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <QColor>
#include <GL/gl.h>

//#include <QGLWidget>
//#include <QtWidgets>

#include <QMatrix4x4>
#include <QVector3D>

#include <qmath.h>


class Patch;
class Geometry;

//! [0]
class QtLogo : public QObject
{
public:
    QtLogo(QObject *parent, int d = 64, qreal s = 1.0);
    ~QtLogo();
    void setColor(QColor c);
    void draw() const;
private:
    void buildGeometry(int d, qreal s);

    QList<Patch *> parts;
    Geometry *geom;
};
//! [0]

#endif // QTLOGO_H
```

window.h

```
// window.h


#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H


//#include <QObject>

//#include <QApplication>
//#include <QHBoxLayout>

//#include <QSpinBox>
//#include <QKeyEvent>

#include <QWidget>
#include <QSlider>

class QSlider;

class GLWidget;

namespace Ui {
class Window;
}

class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Window();

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::Window *ui;
    QSlider *createSlider();

    GLWidget *glWidget;
    QSlider *xSlider;
    QSlider *ySlider;
    QSlider *zSlider;


};

#endif
```

glwidget.cpp

```
// glwidget.cpp


#include <math.h>

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include "glwidget.h"
#include "qtlogo.h"

//#include <QColor>

/*
#ifndef GL_MULTISAMPLE
#define GL_MULTISAMPLE  0x809D
#endif
*/


GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers), parent)
{
    logo = 0;
    xRot = 0;
    yRot = 0;
    zRot = 0;

    qtGreen = QColor::fromCmykF(0.40, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    qtPurple = QColor::fromCmykF(0.39, 0.39, 0.0, 0.0);
}

GLWidget::~GLWidget()
{
}

QSize GLWidget::minimumSizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(50, 50); //
}

QSize GLWidget::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(800, 800);
}

static void qNormalizeAngle(int &angle)
{
    while (angle < 0)
        angle += 360 * 16;
    while (angle > 360 * 16)
        angle -= 360 * 16;
}

void GLWidget::setXRotation(int angle)
{
    qNormalizeAngle(angle);
    if (angle != xRot) {
        xRot = angle;
        emit xRotationChanged(angle);
        updateGL();
    }
}

void GLWidget::setYRotation(int angle)
{
    qNormalizeAngle(angle);
    if (angle != yRot) {
        yRot = angle;
        emit yRotationChanged(angle);
        updateGL();
    }
}

void GLWidget::setZRotation(int angle)
{
    qNormalizeAngle(angle);
    if (angle != zRot) {
        zRot = angle;

        emit zRotationChanged(angle);
        updateGL();
    }
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(qtPurple.dark());

    logo = new QtLogo(this, 64);
    logo->setColor(qtGreen.dark());

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    static GLfloat lightPosition[4] = { 0.5, 5.0, 7.0, 1.0 };
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -10.0);
    glRotatef(xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    logo->draw();
    //logo->setColor(QColor(0,0,0));
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    int side = qMin(width, height);
    glViewport((width - side) / 2, (height - side) / 2, side, side);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
#ifdef QT_OPENGL_ES_1
    glOrthof(-0.5, +0.5, -0.5, +0.5, 4.0, 15.0);
#else
    glOrtho(-0.5, +0.5, -0.5, +0.5, 4.0, 15.0);
#endif
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    lastPos = event->pos();
}

void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    int dx = event->x() - lastPos.x();
    int dy = event->y() - lastPos.y();

    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        setXRotation(xRot + 8 * dy);
        setYRotation(yRot + 8 * dx);
    } else if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
        setXRotation(xRot + 8 * dy);
        setZRotation(zRot + 8 * dx);
    }
    lastPos = event->pos();
}
```

main.cpp

```
// main.cpp


#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <QtGui>

#include <QApplication>

#include <QDesktopWidget>

#include "window.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Window window;
    window.resize(window.sizeHint());
    int desktopArea = QApplication::desktop()->width() *
                     QApplication::desktop()->height();
    int widgetArea = window.width() * window.height();
    if (((float)widgetArea / (float)desktopArea) < 0.75f)
        window.show();
    else
        window.showMaximized();
    return app.exec();
}
```

qtlogo.cpp

```
// qtlogo.cpp


#include "qtlogo.h"


static const qreal tee_height = 0.311126;
static const qreal cross_width = 0.25;
static const qreal bar_thickness = 0.113137;
static const qreal inside_diam = 0.20;
static const qreal outside_diam = 0.30;
static const qreal logo_depth = 0.10;
static const int num_divisions = 32;

//! [0]
struct Geometry
{
    QVector<GLushort> faces;
    QVector<QVector3D> vertices;
    QVector<QVector3D> normals;
    void appendSmooth(const QVector3D &a, const QVector3D &n, int from);
    void appendFaceted(const QVector3D &a, const QVector3D &n);
    void finalize();
    void loadArrays() const;
};
//! [0]

//! [1]
class Patch
{
public:
    enum Smoothing { Faceted, Smooth };
    Patch(Geometry *);
    void setSmoothing(Smoothing s) { sm = s; }
    void translate(const QVector3D &t);
    void rotate(qreal deg, QVector3D axis);
    void draw() const;
    void addTri(const QVector3D &a, const QVector3D &b, const QVector3D &c, const QVector3D &n);
    void addQuad(const QVector3D &a, const QVector3D &b,  const QVector3D &c, const QVector3D &d);

    GLushort start;
    GLushort count;
    GLushort initv;

    GLfloat faceColor[4];
    QMatrix4x4 mat;
    Smoothing sm;
    Geometry *geom;
};
//! [1]

static inline void qSetColor(float colorVec[], QColor c)
{
    colorVec[0] = c.redF();
    colorVec[1] = c.greenF();
    colorVec[2] = c.blueF();
    colorVec[3] = c.alphaF();
}

void Geometry::loadArrays() const
{
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices.constData());
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals.constData());
}

void Geometry::finalize()
{
    // TODO: add vertex buffer uploading here

    // Finish smoothing normals by ensuring accumulated normals are returned
    // to length 1.0.
    for (int i = 0; i < normals.count(); ++i)
        normals[i].normalize();
}

void Geometry::appendSmooth(const QVector3D &a, const QVector3D &n, int from)
{
    // Smooth normals are acheived by averaging the normals for faces meeting
    // at a point.  First find the point in geometry already generated
    // (working backwards, since most often the points shared are between faces
    // recently added).
    int v = vertices.count() - 1;
    for ( ; v >= from; --v)
        if (qFuzzyCompare(vertices[v], a))
            break;
    if (v < from)
    {
        // The vert was not found so add it as a new one, and initialize
        // its corresponding normal
        v = vertices.count();
        vertices.append(a);
        normals.append(n);
    }
    else
    {
        // Vert found, accumulate normals into corresponding normal slot.
        // Must call finalize once finished accumulating normals
        normals[v] += n;
    }
    // In both cases (found or not) reference the vert via its index
    faces.append(v);
}

void Geometry::appendFaceted(const QVector3D &a, const QVector3D &n)
{
    // Faceted normals are achieved by duplicating the vert for every
    // normal, so that faces meeting at a vert get a sharp edge.
    int v = vertices.count();
    vertices.append(a);
    normals.append(n);
    faces.append(v);
}

Patch::Patch(Geometry *g)
   : start(g->faces.count())
   , count(0)
   , initv(g->vertices.count())
   , sm(Patch::Smooth)
   , geom(g)
{
    qSetColor(faceColor, QColor(Qt::darkGray));
}

void Patch::rotate(qreal deg, QVector3D axis)
{
    mat.rotate(deg, axis);
}

void Patch::translate(const QVector3D &t)
{
    mat.translate(t);
}

static inline void qMultMatrix(const QMatrix4x4 &mat)
{
    if (sizeof(qreal) == sizeof(GLfloat))
        glMultMatrixf((GLfloat*)mat.constData());
#ifndef QT_OPENGL_ES
    else if (sizeof(qreal) == sizeof(GLdouble))
        glMultMatrixd((GLdouble*)mat.constData());
#endif
    else
    {
        GLfloat fmat[16];
        GLfloat const *r = mat.constData();
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
            fmat[i] = r[i];
        glMultMatrixf(fmat);
    }
}

//! [2]
void Patch::draw() const
{
    glPushMatrix();
    qMultMatrix(mat);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, faceColor);

    const GLushort *indices = geom->faces.constData();
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices + start);
    glPopMatrix();
}
//! [2]

void Patch::addTri(const QVector3D &a, const QVector3D &b, const QVector3D &c, const QVector3D &n)
{
    QVector3D norm = n.isNull() ? QVector3D::normal(a, b, c) : n;
    if (sm == Smooth)
    {
        geom->appendSmooth(a, norm, initv);
        geom->appendSmooth(b, norm, initv);
        geom->appendSmooth(c, norm, initv);
    }
    else
    {
        geom->appendFaceted(a, norm);
        geom->appendFaceted(b, norm);
        geom->appendFaceted(c, norm);
    }
    count += 3;
}

void Patch::addQuad(const QVector3D &a, const QVector3D &b,  const QVector3D &c, const QVector3D &d)
{
    QVector3D norm = QVector3D::normal(a, b, c);
    if (sm == Smooth)
    {
        addTri(a, b, c, norm);
        addTri(a, c, d, norm);
    }
    else
    {
        // If faceted share the two common verts
        addTri(a, b, c, norm);
        int k = geom->vertices.count();
        geom->appendSmooth(a, norm, k);
        geom->appendSmooth(c, norm, k);
        geom->appendFaceted(d, norm);
        count += 3;
    }
}

static inline QVector<QVector3D> extrude(const QVector<QVector3D> &verts, qreal depth)
{
    QVector<QVector3D> extr = verts;
    for (int v = 0; v < extr.count(); ++v)
        extr[v].setZ(extr[v].z() - depth);
    return extr;
}

class Rectoid
{
public:
    void translate(const QVector3D &t)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.count(); ++i)
            parts[i]->translate(t);
    }
    void rotate(qreal deg, QVector3D axis)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.count(); ++i)
            parts[i]->rotate(deg, axis);
    }

    // No special Rectoid destructor - the parts are fetched out of this member
    // variable, and destroyed by the new owner
    QList<Patch*> parts;
};

class RectPrism : public Rectoid
{
public:
    RectPrism(Geometry *g, qreal width, qreal height, qreal depth);
};

RectPrism::RectPrism(Geometry *g, qreal width, qreal height, qreal depth)
{
    enum { bl, br, tr, tl };
    Patch *fb = new Patch(g);
    fb->setSmoothing(Patch::Faceted);

    // front face
    QVector<QVector3D> r(4);
    r[br].setX(width);
    r[tr].setX(width);
    r[tr].setY(height);
    r[tl].setY(height);
    QVector3D adjToCenter(-width / 2.0, -height / 2.0, depth / 2.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        r[i] += adjToCenter;
    fb->addQuad(r[bl], r[br], r[tr], r[tl]);

    // back face
    QVector<QVector3D> s = extrude(r, depth);
    fb->addQuad(s[tl], s[tr], s[br], s[bl]);

    // side faces
    Patch *sides = new Patch(g);
    sides->setSmoothing(Patch::Faceted);
    sides->addQuad(s[bl], s[br], r[br], r[bl]);
    sides->addQuad(s[br], s[tr], r[tr], r[br]);
    sides->addQuad(s[tr], s[tl], r[tl], r[tr]);
    sides->addQuad(s[tl], s[bl], r[bl], r[tl]);

    parts << fb << sides;
}

class RectTorus : public Rectoid
{
public:
    RectTorus(Geometry *g, qreal iRad, qreal oRad, qreal depth, int numSectors);
};

RectTorus::RectTorus(Geometry *g, qreal iRad, qreal oRad, qreal depth, int k)
{
    QVector<QVector3D> inside;
    QVector<QVector3D> outside;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        qreal angle = (i * 2 * M_PI) / k;
        inside << QVector3D(iRad * qSin(angle), iRad * qCos(angle), depth / 2.0);
        outside << QVector3D(oRad * qSin(angle), oRad * qCos(angle), depth / 2.0);
    }
    inside << QVector3D(0.0, iRad, 0.0);
    outside << QVector3D(0.0, oRad, 0.0);
    QVector<QVector3D> in_back = extrude(inside, depth);
    QVector<QVector3D> out_back = extrude(outside, depth);

    // Create front, back and sides as separate patches so that smooth normals
    // are generated for the curving sides, but a faceted edge is created between
    // sides and front/back
    Patch *front = new Patch(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        front->addQuad(outside[i], inside[i],
                       inside[(i + 1) % k], outside[(i + 1) % k]);
    Patch *back = new Patch(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        back->addQuad(in_back[i], out_back[i],
                      out_back[(i + 1) % k], in_back[(i + 1) % k]);
    Patch *is = new Patch(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        is->addQuad(in_back[i], in_back[(i + 1) % k],
                    inside[(i + 1) % k], inside[i]);
    Patch *os = new Patch(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        os->addQuad(out_back[(i + 1) % k], out_back[i],
                    outside[i], outside[(i + 1) % k]);
    parts << front << back << is << os;
}

QtLogo::QtLogo(QObject *parent, int divisions, qreal scale)
    : QObject(parent)
    , geom(new Geometry())
{
    buildGeometry(divisions, scale);
}

QtLogo::~QtLogo()
{
    qDeleteAll(parts);
    delete geom;
}

void QtLogo::setColor(QColor c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.count(); ++i)
        qSetColor(parts[i]->faceColor, c);
}

//! [3]
void QtLogo::buildGeometry(int divisions, qreal scale)
{
    qreal cw = cross_width * scale;
    qreal bt = bar_thickness * scale;
    qreal ld = logo_depth * scale;
    qreal th = tee_height *scale;

    RectPrism cross(geom, cw, bt, ld);
    RectPrism stem(geom, bt, th, ld);

    QVector3D z(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    cross.rotate(45.0, z);
    stem.rotate(45.0, z);

    qreal stem_downshift = (th + bt) / 2.0;
    stem.translate(QVector3D(0.0, -stem_downshift, 0.0));

    RectTorus body(geom, 0.20, 0.30, 0.1, divisions);

    parts << stem.parts << cross.parts << body.parts;

    geom->finalize();
}
//! [3]

//! [4]
void QtLogo::draw() const
{
    geom->loadArrays();

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.count(); ++i)
        parts[i]->draw();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
}
//! [4]
```

window.cpp

```
// window.cpp


#include <QtWidgets>
#include "window.h"
#include "ui_window.h"
#include "glwidget.h"
#include <QSlider>

Window::Window(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Window)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //glWidget = new GLWidget;
    glWidget = ui->widget;

    xSlider = createSlider();
    ySlider = createSlider();
    zSlider = createSlider();

    connect(xSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), glWidget, SLOT(setXRotation(int)));
    connect(glWidget, SIGNAL(xRotationChanged(int)), xSlider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    connect(ySlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), glWidget, SLOT(setYRotation(int)));
    connect(glWidget, SIGNAL(yRotationChanged(int)), ySlider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    connect(zSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), glWidget, SLOT(setZRotation(int)));
    connect(glWidget, SIGNAL(zRotationChanged(int)), zSlider, SLOT(setValue(int)));

    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(glWidget);
    mainLayout->addWidget(xSlider);
    mainLayout->addWidget(ySlider);
    mainLayout->addWidget(zSlider);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    xSlider->setValue(15 * 16);
    ySlider->setValue(345 * 16);
    zSlider->setValue(0 * 16);
    setWindowTitle(tr("Hello GL"));
}

QSlider *Window::createSlider()
{
    QSlider *slider = new QSlider(Qt::Vertical);
    slider->setRange(0, 360 * 16);
    slider->setSingleStep(16);
    slider->setPageStep(15 * 16);
    slider->setTickInterval(15 * 16);
    slider->setTickPosition(QSlider::TicksRight);
    return slider;
}

Window::~Window()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Window::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if (e->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
        close();
    else
        QWidget::keyPressEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: tl;dr, but try installing latest graphics drivers from GPU maker.

Comment: Thankyou, the latest drivers are installed. Same problem. There is something QT5 does not which QT4 does regarding OpenGL. I just don't know the workaround after Google-ing my eyeballs out.

Comment: I have also tried this QT hello world example in the Linux QT and although the application runs, no Q logo graphic is displayed. So damn annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:-) I have nailed it!

The problem was: The Q Logo does not appear in QT5. Although it does work in QT4.

After spending weeks on this problem, googling for hours, going through the hassle of compiling QT many many times, I have finally solved the problem with this code and the mystery of opengl_es and ANGLE

So for those of us completely baffled as to why QT OpenGL examples code prior to QT5 may not work or work properly, it could be the same issue as this code.

Basically comment out or omit references to QT_OPENGL_ES.

In this hello world Q example:

Comment this out as shown contained in the Qlogo.cpp file

```
    /*
#ifndef QT_OPENGL_ES
    else if (sizeof(qreal) == sizeof(GLdouble))
    glMultMatrixd((GLdouble*)mat.constData());
#endif
*/
```

Lots of code lovin' to you all.

Comment: Thanks for this. Maybe you're not even using StackOverflow any more, but in case you are: your post help me get a sample up and running faster.